# membership issue after online hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a shopping cart asp.net application presently i manage login system by simply making a DB table with 2 field username and password and in my web.config file redirect all the user to login page by authentication and authorization tag

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
 <forms  defaultUrl="default.aspx" loginUrl="login1.aspx"   cookieless="AutoDetect"  ></forms>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
```

and on my login page simply compare username/pwd entered by user with database entry and if the user is correct calling the function

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
```

that redirect the user to home page it works very fine on my local system and i have no issue.But recently i hosted my application online and there is some issue with my login system.When i login into the site its ok but after some time user is automatically thrown out of site to the login page and he has to login again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your users are bumping up against a cookie expiry. Add the following attributes to your `<forms>` element:

```
<forms defaultUrl="default.aspx" loginUrl="login1.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" />
```

By default, sliding expiration SHOULD be set to true, but if it's not, 30 minutes after a user logs in, their authentication will expire no matter if they've visited other site pages since that time. By default, the timeout period is also supposed to be set to 30 minutes from last refresh, so if your user is idle for 30 minutes, they will have to renew the authentication cookie in order to access secured content. You can extend this to whatever value you like, such as "60" in the above example.

You can find out more about these attributes at the [MSDN reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx).

Comment: I did that but not works for me                                <forms  defaultUrl="default.aspx" loginUrl="login1.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60"  ></forms>